# How to create and fire a custom event in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-event-emitter

I'm new in Angular and I've read about event binding so I can do something like this:

```
<button (click)="doSomething()"></button>
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a custom event and do the same thing. Let's say that I want to have a custom event like: `deleteItem`, is it possible to do something like this? And how?

```
<my-component (deleteItem)="doSomething()"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Of course, you can use an `eventEmitter`
in my-component ts file add this

```
 @Output() deleteItem= new EventEmitter();
```

and when you want to rise the event do this

```
  this.deleteItem.emit();
```

also you can pass data like this

```
  this.countUpdate.emit({value: some data });
```

then catch it in the parent component like this

```
<my-component (deleteItem)="doSomething($event)"></my-component>
```

and in the parent ts file

```
    doSomething(event)
    { 
       console.log(event);
    }
```

Comment: It is also important to have the import statement as "import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';" rather than "import { EventEmitter } from 'events';" (thanks vs code auto import)

Answer (score 5):

You should check out Angular's documentations example for *parent listens to child event*:

You declare a class property with the `@Output()` decorator and instantiate it to a new EventEmitter instance.

Example from the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-voter',
  template: `
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <button (click)="vote(true)"  [disabled]="didVote">Agree</button>
    <button (click)="vote(false)" [disabled]="didVote">Disagree</button>
  `
})
export class VoterComponent {
  @Input()  name: string;
  @Output() voted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  didVote = false;

  vote(agreed: boolean) {
    this.voted.emit(agreed);
    this.didVote = true;
  }
}
```

**Remember it is good practice to always add generic typing to the EventEmitter if it emits a value.**

If an event emits a boolean value you should instantiate it with `@Output() eventName = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`

The component above could be used in a parent component with `<app-voter (voted)="handleVote($event)"></app-voter>`

Answer (score 3):

EventEmitter can used to create your own custom events, eventemitter are objects in angular framework.

`@Output() deleteItem= new EventEmitter<{itemName:string}>(); ItemName=''; this.deleteItem.emit({ItemName=this.itemName});`

Answer (score 2):

```
@Output() loaderStatus= new EventEmitter<{Status:boolean}>(); Status=true; 
this.loaderEvent.emit({Status=false});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).